# Junit tets case for different values return from method every time when i execute and need to compare with enum values

Tags: java, junit

My method returns different values when ever i execute for example it returns abc for 1st execution and cde for 2nd execution so i want to assertequla that values with enum values so plz tell me how to write junit test case.Enum is`abc("abc"),cde("cde");`. Sample Junit tets case is

```
@Test 
public void test() {
    assertEquals(Enum.abc,mymethod.getvalue());
}
```

Comment: What does mymethod.getvalue() do?

Comment: It is a method in my class which returns random values @JensS

Comment: You want to assert that whatever getvalue returns is one of your enum values, correct?

Comment: yes  u r right @JensS

Answer (score 0):

To `assertEqauls` an Enum, use its `toString()` method:

```
@Test 
public void test() {
   assertEquals(Enum.abc.toString(), mymethod.getvalue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if something is in the Enum, you need a construct like this:

```
public class EnumTest {

    enum TestEnum {
        ABC("abc"),
        DEF("def");

        String value;

        TestEnum(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        assertTrue(isInEnum("abc"));
        assertTrue(isInEnum("def"));
        assertFalse(isInEnum("ghj"));
    }

    static boolean isInEnum(String value) {
        for (TestEnum test : TestEnum.values()) {
            if(test.getValue().equals(value)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```